# Visual Studio: сравнить два текстовых файла

Tags: visual-studio

Как в **Visual Studio** сравнить два текстовых файла, чтобы получить подсветку отличий: когда удаленные фрагменты подсвечиваются красным цветом, а добавленные фрагменты выделяются зеленым цветом?

Comment: winmerge чем не устроил?

Comment: А студия вообще такое умеет?

Comment: Вы ведь хотите именно в студии и никакие сторонние средства в духе _Araxis Merge_ вам не подходят?

Comment: какая версия студии?

Comment: Файлы надо сравнивать именно в Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В `Visual Studio` (начиная с 12ой версии) вы можете это сделать посредством ввода в `CommandWindow` (`"View\Other Windows\Command Window"`, либо через `Ctrl+W, A`) команды `Tools.DiffFiles` после которой через пробел указать полное (ну или относительное) имя к каждому из сравниваемых файлов.

Например, должно получиться что-то в духе:

```
Tools.DiffFiles D:\...\leftFile.cpp D:\...\rightFile.cpp
```

Либо вы это можете сделать посредством расширений для студии, таких как: [VSCommands](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8) и [CompareFiles](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56f99a33-46b9-4d9e-8145-900aaba9951d), которые к тому же имеют графический интерфейс непосредственно для таких действий.

---

А вообще, вот нашел схожее на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752998/compare-two-files-in-visual-studio-2012).

Comment: Теперь можно просто выделить через crtl 2 файла, нажать правой кнопкой мыши и в контекстном меню выбрать "Сравнить выбранное"